# Loop to print over a few hundred files with a specific task

Tags: bash

I have a couple hundred files such as A.vcf, B.vcf of which I want to extract the 7th column separated by `:` and then get an output.

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.0
##reference=chrRCRS
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Reads covering the REF position">
##FORMAT=<ID=HF,Number=.,Type=Float,Description="Heteroplasmy Frequency of variant allele">
##FORMAT=<ID=CILOW,Number=.,Type=Float,Description="Value defining the lower limit of the confidence interval of the heteroplasmy fraction">
##FORMAT=<ID=CIUP,Number=.,Type=Float,Description="Value defining the upper limit of the confidence interval of the heteroplasmy fraction">
##FORMAT=<ID=SDP,Number=.,Type=String,Description="Strand-specific read depth of the ALT allele">
##INFO=<ID=AC,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Allele count in genotypes">
##INFO=<ID=AN,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total number of alleles in called genotypes">
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  SRR5137814_1
chrMT   64      .       C       T       .       PASS    AC=1;AN=1       GT:DP:HF:CILOW:CIUP:SDP 1:57:1.0:0.924:1.0:26;31
chrMT   73      .       A       G       .       PASS    AC=1;AN=1       GT:DP:HF:CILOW:CIUP:SDP 1:59:1.0:0.927:1.0:24;35
chrMT   146     .       T       C       .       PASS    AC=1;AN=2       GT:DP:HF:CILOW:CIUP:SDP 0/1:49:0.939:0.829:0.985:21;25
chrMT   153     .       A       G       .       PASS    AC=1;AN=2       GT:DP:HF:CILOW:CIUP:SDP 0/1:46:0.978:0.876:1.0:19;26
chrMT   235     .       A       G       .       PASS    AC=1;AN=1       GT:DP:HF:CILOW:CIUP:SDP 1:56:1.0:0.923:1.0:22;34
chrMT   263     .       A       G       .       PASS    AC=1;AN=2       GT:DP:HF:CILOW:CIUP:SDP 0/1:56:0.982:0.897:1.0:25;30
chrMT   302     .       A       AC      .       PASS    AC=1;AN=2       GT:DP:HF:CILOW:CIUP:SDP 0/1:32:0.188:0.089:0.354:0;6
chrMT   309     .       C       CCT     .       PASS    AC=1;AN=2       GT:DP:HF:CILOW:CIUP:SDP 0/1:34:0.265:0.146:0.431:0;9
```

In this format, I have a couple 100 files. I want to get the output of the DP column for each file and also the max and the min value of DP per file. The name of each file should be there and all this can be in an txt file output.
Please advise.

Sample Output for DP:

FILE               MAX    MIN
SRRXXXX             13     1

SRRXXXY             12     2

and so

Comment: It is unclear what is your input files and what is your desired output file. I suggest you show a couple of lines in th A.vcf file for example. As for the filename not written by `awk`, you need to set the file as a variable, e.g. `awk -F ':' -v file="$file" '{print file, $7}' > ${file}` (the important option is `-v file="$file"`)

Comment: ##fileformat=VCFv4.0
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Reads covering the REF position">
##FORMAT=<ID=HF,Number=.,Type=Float,Description="Heteroplasmy F
##INFO=<ID=AN,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total number of alleles in called genotypes">
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  SRR5137814_1
chrMT   64      .       C       T       .       PASS    AC=1;AN=1         GT:DP:HF:CILOW:CIUP:SDP 1:57:1.0:0.924:1.0:26;31

Comment: My desired output file could be a text file. The input is a vcf file

Comment: You should edit your question to include this information, and make sure the formatting matches correctly your input and output. I’m pretty sure the question you wrote does not correspond to what data you have or what you want to have. Please check https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: please review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question; of particular interest (to me) ... the desired output ... if all output is to be appended to the *vcf file (as indicated in your code snippet) or to some other file (and if so, what is the name said file(s)) ... the additional requirement for min/max (as per your comment to my answer) and what the output should look like with min/max included ...

Comment: please update the question to show the expected output for that sample input file; your earlier edit showed 3 output values from field #7, but this (latest) sample input file shows 8 `chrMT` lines (I'm assuming you want to ignore lines starting with `#`) ... so it's not clear how you reduce 7 lines to 3 values ... hence the need for you to provide more details (eg, desired outpu)

Comment: i updated the quesion

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Following is based on the initial question and desired output (it appears the question and format of the desired output is undergoing some edits ... ???)

---

Assumptions:

- the name of each output section is the name of the input file minus the path and `.vcf` extension
- each file has exactly 3 lines with at least 7 fields (delimited by `:`)

Sample data:

```
$ cat test/A.vcf
line1:f2:f3:f4:f5:f6:12:f8:
line2:f2:f3:f4:f5:f6:12:f8:
line3:f2:f3:f4:f5:f6:13:f8:
$ cat test/B.vcf
line1:f2:f3:f4:f5:f6:13:f8:
line2:f2:f3:f4:f5:f6:13:f8:
line3:f2:f3:f4:f5:f6:12:f8:
$ cat test/C.vcf
line1:f2:f3:f4:f5:f6:20:f8:
line2:f2:f3:f4:f5:f6:21:f8:
line3:f2:f3:f4:f5:f6:22:f8:
```

For printing the filename (sans path and `.vcf`) we'll run a couple `awk/split` commands against the builtin variable `FILENAME`:

```
# define ":" as our input file delimiter

awk -F":" '

# FNR==1 => processing a new file so time to parse and print FILENAME

FNR==1 { if ( FNR!=NR ) { printf "\n" }    # FNR!=NR => not the first file so print a blank line to separate output sections
         n=split(FILENAME,arr1,"/")        # split FILENAME by "/" and place parts in array "arr1"
         split(arr1[n],arr2,".")           # split last element of arr1 by "." and place parts in array "arr2"
         print arr2[1] }                   # print first element of arr2

       { print $7 }                        # for all input lines => print field #7
' test/*.vcf
```

NOTE: Remove the comment blocks to reduce clutter.

Running the above against our 3x *vcf files generates:

```
A
12
12
13

B
13
13
12

C
20
21
22
```

Comment: How do I get this in an output txt file?

Comment: Also if I want to output the max and min values of $7

Comment: please update the question with more details, in particular ... your current code snippet shows you appending the output to the input/vcf file; it's not clear (to me) what the expected output is to be (your output and @vdavid's edit don't match); your original question mentions nothing about min/max, let alone what the desired output should look like with min/max included

Comment: This works and gives me the output , but I am wondering how to also output the min and max values of the column for each file